# Looking for a nontrivial upper bound to the function $f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n}\phi(d)/d$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For a natural number $n$, let $f(n) := \sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\phi(d)}{d}$, where $\phi$ is the Euler-phi function. I believe this is a multiplicative function. I'm looking for a nontrivial (sublinear) upper bound for it - ie, a reasonably simple and explicit monotonically increasing function $B(n)$ such that

1. $f(n)\le B(n)$ for all $n\ge 1$, and moreover
2. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{B(n)}{n} = 0$

This function came up in my research. I can see that the worst case scenario happens when $n$ has many distinct prime divisors, though I'm not an analytic number theorist it's not obvious how to get a nontrivial upper bound to me. In any case, this is a simple enough looking function that I assume there must be results on this somewhere (which are presumably better than anything I could come up with given some time).

I'm particularly interested in an upper bound to the function $f$ when it's restricted to numbers of the form $p\pm 1$, where $p$ is a prime, in case this particular case has been studied.

Comment: Since $\phi(d)\le d$, clearly $f(n) \le d(n)$ where $d(n)$ denotes the number of divisors of $n$.   Pairing a divisor $d$ with $n/d$, and noting that at least one of  $d$ or $n/d$ must be $\le \sqrt{n}$, one sees easily that $d(n) \le 2\sqrt{n}$.  Of course much more be said (e.g. $d(n) \le C(\epsilon) n^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon >0$), but this may be enough for you.  Look up bounds for divisor function in (just about) any elementary number theory book.

Comment: This is a multiplicative function; on prime powers, it satisfies $f(p^r) = \sum_{j = 0}^{r} \phi(p^j) p^{-j} = \sum_{j = 0}^{r} (1 - p^{-1}) = (1 - p^{-1}) (r + 1)$ since $\phi(p^j) = p^j (1 - p^{-1})$. So $f(n) = \frac{\phi(n)}{n} \tau(n)$, where $\tau(n) = \# \{d \mid n\}$ denotes the divisor function. Of course $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} \leq 1$, while upper bounds for the divisor function are well-known: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function. Note that these are "worst case" bounds, which are at primorials $n = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_m$, which cannot be of the form $p \pm 1$.

Comment: If $n=\prod_{i=1}^{r} p_i^{a_i}$, then $f(n)=\prod_{i=1}^{r}(\sigma_i+1)$, where $\sigma_i=(1-\frac{1}{p_i})a_i$.

Comment: @Lucia Ah, great! That's an excellent observation. If you'd like to put that as an answer I'd be happy to mark this question answered. Thanks!

Comment: Also, $ln(n)+\sum_{i=1}^{N} ln(p_i)= \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\sigma_i+1)ln(p_i)(\frac{p_i}{p_i-1})$. Say, $\sum_{i=1}^{N} ln(p_i)(\frac{p_i}{p_i-1})=\chi$ Hence, $f(n) \leq \left(1+\frac{ln(n)}{\chi}\right)^{\chi}$. Here, $N$ can be chosen as big as possible. $p_i := i$th prime number.

Comment: Now, the function $T(x)=(1+\frac{c}{x})^x$ is minimum when $x≈\frac{c}{e-1}$. So, from the bound of $f(n)$, we can choose primes (or the limit $N$, the prime factors of $n$  must be chosen) such that $\chi≈\frac{ln(n)}{e-1}$. Hence, $f(n)≤e^{\frac{ln(n)}{e-1}}=n^{\frac{1}{e-1}}$. So, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{n} ≤ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{e-2}{e-1}}}=0$.